# how i can decrease post size?

Tags: html, wordpress, themes

i want to decrease post size. i mean when i post anything in my site i want to increase left and right side space for post.how i can do it?(post write wide size want to be decrease)
my all post css code show below.[my site](http://dewdropzone.com)

```
/***** Post Lead Image *****/
#lead-image { position: relative; width: 610px; height: 320px; margin: 0 10px 20px; padding: 5px; background: url(images/backgrounds/bg-postthumb.gif); }
#lead-image img { display: block; }

/***** Post Meta *****/
.published { position: relative; width: 620px; margin: 0 10px 20px; background: url(images/backgrounds/bg-published.gif) repeat-x 0 0; text-align: center; }
.published p { background: #fff url(images/backgrounds/bg-published-decoration.gif) no-repeat center bottom; display: inline-block; color: #222; font: 1.2em 'VollkornItalic', serif; padding: 0 10px 20px; }
.published p a, .published p a:visited { text-decoration: none; }
.published p a:hover, .published p a:active { text-decoration: underline; }

/***** Post YouTube Video Player *****/
#video-player { position: relative; width: 620px; margin: 0 10px 20px; }
.yt-player { width: 615px; height: 370px; }

/***** Post Entry *****/
.post-columns { position: relative; width: 640px; }
.post-460 { position: relative; width: 460px; margin: 0 10px; float: right; }
.post-620, .periodic-password-post { position: relative; width: 620px; margin: 0 10px; }
.post-940 { width: 940px; margin: 0 10px; }
.post-left-column { position: relative; width: 160px; float: left; margin: 0 0 20px; }
.post-entry { position: relative; }
.post-entry h1, .post-entry h2, .post-entry h3, .post-entry h4, .post-entry h5, .post-entry h6 { margin: 0 0 10px; color: #222; line-height: 1.7; }
.post-entry h1 { font-size: 2.1em; }
.post-entry h2 { font-size: 1.9em; }
.post-entry h3 { font-size: 1.7em; }
.post-entry h4 { font-size: 1.5em; }
.post-entry h5 { font-size: 1.3em; }
.post-entry h6 { font-size: 1.2em; }
.post-entry p { font-size: 1.3em; line-height: 1.7em; margin: 0 0 30px; }
.post-entry blockquote { margin: 0 40px; border-left: 3px solid #464646; padding: 0 0 0 20px; font: 120% 'VollkornItalic', serif; color: #222; }
.post-entry blockquote p { line-height: 1.5em; }
.post-entry ul, .post-entry ol { margin: 0 40px 30px; font-size: 1.3em; line-height: 1.7em; }
.post-entry ul { list-style: disc; }
.post-entry ul ul { margin: 0 0 0 30px; font-size: inherit; list-style: circle; }
.post-entry ul ol { margin: 0 0 0 30px; font-size: inherit; }
.post-entry ul ul li { background: none; padding: 0; }
.post-entry ol { list-style: decimal; }
.post-entry dl { font-size: 1.3em; line-height: 1.7em; }
.post-entry dt { color: #222; font-weight: bold; }
.post-entry dd { margin: 0 0 30px; }
.post-entry code { font: 90% Monaco, Courier, monospace; background: #f1f1f1; padding: 2px; border-bottom: 1px solid #d9d9d9; border-right: 1px solid #d9d9d9; }
.post-entry p a, .post-entry li a,
.post-entry p a:visited, .post-entry li a:visited { text-decoration: none; }
.post-entry p a:hover, .post-entry li a:hover,
.post-entry p a:active, .post-entry li a:active { text-decoration: underline; }
.post-entry table { width: 90%; border-left: 1px solid #d9d9d9; margin: 0 auto 20px; }
.post-entry table caption { line-height: 3em; font-size: 1.2em; font-weight: bold; color: #464646; }
.post-entry table thead, .post-entry table tfoot { background: #f1f1f1; }
.post-entry table th, .post-entry table td { padding: 10px 15px; text-align: left; border-right: 1px solid #d9d9d9; border-bottom: 1px solid #d9d9d9; font-size: 1.2em; color: #464646; }
.post-entry tfoot td { text-align: center; }
.post-entry table th { border-top: 1px solid #d9d9d9; font-weight: bold; }
.post-entry table td a, .post-entry table td a:visited { font-weight: bold; text-decoration: none; }
.post-entry table td a:hover, .post-entry table td a:active { text-decoration: underline; }
.post-entry pre { font-size: 1.4em; background: url(images/backgrounds/bg-pre.gif) top left; line-height: 2.3em; width: 600px; overflow: auto; overflow-y: hidden; border: 1px solid #d9d9d9; margin: 0 0 20px; }
.post-entry pre code { background: none; border: none; font-size: inherit; margin: 0 20px; padding: 18px 0; }
.post-entry address { font-style: normal; font-size: 1.3em; line-height: 1.5em; margin: 0 0 20px; }
.post-entry strong { color: #464646; }

/***** Post Entry Password Form ****/
.post-entry form label { font-weight: bold; }
.post-entry form input[type='password'] { width: 280px; padding: 7px 10px; border: 5px solid #f1f1f1; color: #d9d9d9; margin: 5px 0 0; }
.post-entry form input[type='password']:focus { color: #797979; }
.post-entry form input[type='submit'] { width: 140px; height: 40px; margin: 0 0 20px; background: url(images/backgrounds/periodic-sprite-03.png) no-repeat 0 -340px; font-weight: bold; font-family: Arial, "Helvetia Neue", Helvetica, sans-serif; text-transform: uppercase; color: #797979; margin: 10px 0 0; }
.post-entry form input[type='submit']:hover { background-position: 0 -430px; cursor: pointer; }

/***** Shortcodes *****/
.post-entry blockquote.pullquote { margin: 0 20px; padding: 0; width: 35%; border: none; color: #464646; }
.post-entry blockquote.pullquote p { margin: 0; }
.post-entry blockquote.pullright { padding: 5px 0 5px 20px; border-left: 3px solid #464646; }
.post-entry blockquote.pullleft { padding: 5px 20px 5px 0; border-right: 3px solid #464646; text-align: right; }
.checklist { position: relative; }
.checklist ul { list-style: none; }
.checklist li { background: url(images/backgrounds/check.png) no-repeat left .4em; padding: 0 0 0 20px; }
.arrowlist { position: relative; }
.arrowlist ul { list-style: none; }
.arrowlist li { background: url(images/backgrounds/list-arrow.png) no-repeat 0 .4em; padding: 0 0 0 15px; }
.arrowlist li li { background: none; padding: 0; }
.note { position: relative; width: 75%; margin: 0 auto 30px; background: #f1f1f1; border: 1px solid #d9d9d9; padding: 10px 20px 14px; }
.note p { margin: 0; font: 1.4em/1.6em 'VollkornItalic', serif; }
.two_column { position: relative; width: 47%; margin: 0 20px 0 0; float: left; }
.two_column_last { position: relative; width: 47%; margin: 0; float: left; }
.three_column { position: relative; width: 31%; margin: 0 20px 0 0; float: left; }
.three_column_last { position: relative; width: 31%; margin: 0; float: left; }
.four_column { position: relative; width: 23%; margin: 0 20px 0 0; float: left; }
.four_column_last { position: relative; width: 23%; margin: 0; float: left; }
.button, .button:visited { display: inline-block; line-height: 2.5em; text-align: center; background: #e5e5e5 url(images/backgrounds/bg-button.png) repeat-x 0 0; padding: 0 25px; border: 5px solid #d9d9d9; -moz-border-radius: 20px; -webkit-border-radius: 20px; border-radius: 20px; margin: 0 0 20px; color: #464646; font-weight: bold; font-size: 1.2em; text-decoration: none; }
.button:hover, .button:active { background-color: #fcfcfc; background-position: 0 -40px; border-color: #b9b9b9; }

/***** Post Images *****/
img.alignleft { margin: 0 20px 10px 0; }
img.alignright { margin: 0 0 10px 20px; }
img.aligncenter { margin: 0 auto; }

/***** Post Images with Captions *****/
.wp-caption { background: #f3f3f3; border: 1px solid #d9d9d9; padding: 4px 0; }
.wp-caption img { display: block; margin: 0 auto; }
.wp-caption .wp-caption-text { text-align: center; margin: 5px 0 3px; line-height: 1; font: 1.2em/1.3 'VollkornItalic', serif; color: #464646; }
div.alignleft { margin: 0 20px 10px 0; }
div.alignright { margin: 0 0 10px 20px; }
div.aligncenter { margin: 0 auto 20px; }

/***** Post Image Galleries *****/
.gallery { margin: 0 0 20px !important; }
.gallery-item img { border: 1px solid #d9d9d9 !important; background: #f1f1f1; padding: 4px; }
.post-entry dd.gallery-caption { margin: 0 0 15px; padding: 0 20px; }
.post-entry dd.wp-caption-text { font-family: 'VollkornItalic', serif; color: #464646; line-height: 1.2em; }
```

Answer (score 0):

I believe you have fixed the width in every inner container of the div id "left-column" you should make a container inside #left-column and set padding-left and padding-right and make internal div's widths to 100%